# Python - How to find the average height of presidents from selected row numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, sys

I am new to Python and trying to figure out how to pass two arguments that will correspond to the start and stop of a slice, respectively. It will slice the heights column in a csv file with president height.
Then print the average height, rounded to two decimals, of the selected presidents in the following form:

'The average height of presidents number x to y is z'

**I have to use sys and panda for this problem.**

Some example of the csv file looks like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_csv("president_heights.csv")


def president_height(x,y):
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
    result = df.iloc[:x,y].mean(axis=0) 
    return result

x = sys.argv[1]
y = sys.argv[2]
result = president_height(x,y)
print(f'The average height of presidents number {x} to {y} is {result:.2f}')
```

```
The Expected output:
The average height of presidents number 4 to 10 is 177.17

Actual Output:
  IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

I can't figure out how to fix this. Please help!

Comment: Presumably you mean to slice rows `result = df.iloc[x:y,1].mean()` not rows before `x` and column number `y`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using the `iloc[]` correctly. The first argument refers to the rows, whereas the second to the columns therefore it works like: `iloc[start-row:finish-row,start-column:finish-column]`.

Replace this line:

```
 result = df.iloc[:x,y].mean(axis=0)
```

With:

```
 result = df.iloc[x:y,1].mean(axis=0)
```

Comment: Why is `iloc` needed at all here instead of numpy array slicing? `df["height(cm)"][x:y].mean()`

Comment: @Guimoute `iloc` (or `loc`) will always be faster because it indexes once and returns the complete result set. As opposed to isolating a column (returning the Series which may involve re-creating/copying the data) _then_ slicing rows out of the column.